# Unable to get same dimensions of the resulting data even using same preprocessing process

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am a beginner in data science. So, I started from Kaggle's Titanic competition. Everything was good until I came to the stage to preprocess the dataset. I am unable to get the same dimensions of the resulting train and test data when using the following function on both sets:

```
def tsfmr(data):
    ''' Input data format --> pd.DataFrame '''
    tn_num_fts = list(data.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']))
    tn_cat_fts = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['object']))

    num_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
    cat_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='S')

    i_tn_num_fts = num_imp.fit_transform(data[tn_num_fts])
    i_tn_cat_fts = cat_imp.fit_transform(data[tn_cat_fts])
    cat_fts_ohe = ohe.fit_transform(i_tn_cat_fts).toarray()

    return np.hstack([i_tn_num_fts, cat_fts_ohe])
```

Can anyone tell me where is the bug in this code?

I tried to preprocess the data by using a function on both train and test sets.